# numpy, pass individual arguments to np.vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy

if i have an array of x values and want to multiply each x value with a different coefficients and sum the. although I want this operation to happen by passing a function that handles the summation and weighting. for example if i have `x`, `coeffs` and a function, `custom_weight(x, a, b, c)`

```py
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
coeffs = numpy.array([[0.1, 0.2, 3.2], [4.5, 4.0, 0.005]]

def custom_weight(x, a, b, c):
   return a*x**2 + (x+b)**3 + x*c
```

I want `x` to be broadcast for each inner array of `coeffs`. in this case the final result
should be an array with the shape `(6, 2)`. for the first iteration of the `custom_weight` function
should look like this `custom_weight(x[0], *(coeffs[0]))` == `custom_weight(1, 0.1, 0.2, 3.2)`. the same happens for all the other `x`'s  2-6. then this happens again with the `x`'s but now using the second set of coefficients.

I do realize that I could do this manually or `numpy.vectorize` in a certain way... **but I specifically want to use a function in that form**. what I want is some function that would look like so:

```py
numpy.the_function(x, coeffs, axis=0, custom_weight)
# the_function should take each x value and pass it to custom_weight as the first arg.
# then pass the column of coeffs (because axis=0)
# to custom_weight but it should do this by unpacking the column into the args a, b, and c
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more because your `custome_weight` function is not designed to be vectorized. You are looking for something like this:

```
def custom_weight(x, coeffs): 
    return coeffs @ x**np.array([[2,3,1]]).T
```

Output:

```
array([[   3.5  ,    8.4  ,   15.9  ,   27.2  ,   43.5  ,   66.   ],
       [   8.505,   50.01 ,  148.515,  328.02 ,  612.525, 1026.03 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

So after messing around, one solution I found was by vectorizing. transposing the coefficients when passing the arguments to `custom_weight` and then unpacking the coefficients and it will broadcasting and `np.vectorize` takes care of the rest.

```py
import numpy as np

def custom_weight(x, a, b):
    return a*x**2 + b

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
coeffs = np.array([[0.2, 0.6],
                   [1.2, 0.1]])

vec_custom_weight = np.vectorize(custom_weight)
results = vec_custom_weight(xs[:, np.newaxis], *coeffs.T).T
```